# Plugin Inserts content before Page Content

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode

I have a plugin that pulls comic book data from the Marvel API. I have assigned it a short code. When I place the shortcode on the page it does the following:

Before:
[image]

After inserting the shortcode it looks like this:
[image]

```
add_shortcode( 'comic_data', 'get_comics_api' );
```

This is how I defined the shortcode^

The API pull works properly here is the full code leading into the API Call:

```
    defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die;
//give us a menu item with a preview page
add_action( 'admin_menu','marvel_add_menu_page'  );

//make available for shortcode use
add_shortcode( 'comic_data', 'get_comics_api' );

//setup the simple menu
function marvel_add_menu_page(){
    add_menu_page( 
        'Marvel Comics/Movie API',
        'Marvel Comics/Movie API',
        'manage_options',
        'comics-api',
        'get_comics_api',
        'dashicons-book',
        16
    );
}

    function get_comics_api(){
    
    
    //set all the url params needed
    //hid this because it has private key 
    
    //build the url
    $url = $urlbase.$timestamp.$apikeystring.$hashholder.$hashme.$daterange;
    
    //prep the response
    $args = array(
        'headers' => array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        ),
        'body' => array(),
    );

    //get the response
    $response = wp_remote_get( $url, $args );

    //decode the json
    $results = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ));

    echo "<div class='comic-container' style='width:1200px; height:auto; max-width: 1200px;'>"; //container-div
    
    //pull in the items
    foreach($results as $thing){
        
        foreach ($thing->results as $comic ) {
            echo "<div class='comic-content' style='width:200px; height:312px; display:inline-flex;'>"; //content div
            //Create the div with the pic and title, assign ID+push for modal toggle
            echo "<div id='".$comic->id."push'><img src='" .$comic->thumbnail->path . ".jpg' style='max-width: 200px; cursor: pointer;'/><br />" . $comic->title . "</div>";
            
            //Create the modal div with the character informationand with ID to match the comic
            echo "<div id='" . $comic->id . "modal' style='display: none; position: fixed; z-index: 1; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; background-color: rgb(0,0,0); background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);'>
                  <div id='".$comic->id."content' style='background-color: #fefefe; margin: 20% auto; padding: 20px; border: 1px solid #888; width: 50%;'>
                  <p id='".$comic->id."close' style='color: #aaa; float: right; font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer;'>X</p><p>Additional Characters in this Comic:</p>";
            
            //Grab each character
            foreach($comic->characters->items as $characters){
                echo "<div>" . $characters->name . "</div>";
            }
            
            //Modal JS
            echo " <script type='text/javascript'>
                        jQuery('#".$comic->id."push').click(function(){
                        jQuery('#" . $comic->id . "modal').toggle();
                    });
                    jQuery('#".$comic->id."close').click(function(){
                        jQuery('#" . $comic->id . "modal').toggle();
                    });
                   </script>
            
            </div></div>";
            //end modal & content divs
            

         }
        
    }
    echo "</div>"; //close .comic-content div
    echo "</div>"; //close .comic-container div
    
}
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated - this is my first plugin.

Comment: @JacobPeattie - so just replace my 'echo' s with ?> etc......let me give it a go, thanks for the help.

Comment: @JacobPeattie so this works with echo <img src='" .$comic->thumbnail->path . ".jpg' and the source shows up in the html <img src='<?php $comic->thumbnail->path ?>.jpg' did not show up in the src

Comment: I changed all the echo to print <img src='<?php print $comic->thumbnail->path ?>.jpg' style='max-width: 200px; cursor: pointer;'/> - shows the content, still out of place on the page

Comment: Shortcode processing callbacks should always `return` the output. Not `print` or `echo`. If you are dealing with lots of HTML, I recommend to use output buffering.